# xargs: unterminated quote

Tags: ffmpeg, mp3, xargs

I'm trying to convert some .flac files to .mp3, that can I import into iTunes. I tried with find, xargs and ffmpeg, but xargs give me a unterminated quote error (because I have quotes in filename).

That`s my command line:

```
MacKassner:Geto Boys kassner$ find . -type f | egrep "\.flac$" | xargs -I {} ffmpeg -i {} -ab 192k -acodec libmp3lame -ac 2 {}.mp3
```

It`s stop and raise an error in filename "Talkin' Loud Ain't Saying Nothin'.flac".

Some tricks to make this one work?

-- Solved with find only --
find . -type f -name "*.flac" -exec ffmpeg -i {} -ab 192k -acodec libmp3lame -ac 2 {}.mp3 \;

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use GNU Parallel. It is specifically built for this purpose:

```
MacKassner:Geto Boys kassner$ find . -type f | egrep "\.flac$" | parallel ffmpeg -i {} -ab 192k -acodec libmp3lame -ac 2 {}.mp3
```

You may also want to use {.}.mp3 to get rid of the .flac:

```
MacKassner:Geto Boys kassner$ find . -type f | egrep "\.flac$" | parallel ffmpeg -i {} -ab 192k -acodec libmp3lame -ac 2 {.}.mp3
```

Watch the intro video to learn more: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OpaiGYxkSuQ

Comment: Now sure if this could be done in 2011: one can get parallel from homebrew now: homebrew install parallel.

Answer (score 2):

Some versions of xargs support a custom delimiter.  If that's the case, it's as easy as adding `-d'\n'` to indicate that the newline character should be used to separate items (which generally makes sense).

In that case, you'd use it as follows:

```
# find files_containing_quotes/ | xargs -d'\n' -i{} echo "got item '{}'"
```

Comment: Just a shame that xargs on OSX don't support it. Thanks for the tip anyway, I didn't know -d argument.

Answer (score 1):

From the egrep manpage:

```
-Z, --null
          Output  a  zero  byte  (the  ASCII NUL character) instead of the character that normally follows a file
          name.  For example, grep -lZ outputs a zero byte after each file name instead  of  the  usual  newline.
          This  option  makes  the  output  unambiguous,  even  in  the presence of file names containing unusual
          characters like newlines.  This option can be used with commands like find -print0, perl -0,  sort  -z,
          and xargs -0 to process arbitrary file names, even those that contain newline characters.
```

So use -Z with egrep, and -0 with xargs

Comment: egrep with -Z works like a charm, but xargs with -I and -0 is kidding me.

MacKassner:Geto Boys kassner$ find .  | egrep -Z "\.flac$" | xargs -0 -I {} echo {}

And this prints {} once.